# Quick Go project build with Docker without checking in vendor libraries

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose

Currently, we have all vendored libraries in `src/vendor` which makes `docker-compose build` quite fast. Although adding vendored libraries to source control has the disavantage of libraries not being updated and also heavily polluting the diff of pull requests.

Is there a way in between, maybe with caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way in between, maybe with caching?

Yes, several.  But don't fight the system/preferred method.

Use `$GOPATH/src/MyProject/vendor` like you are already doing.

> adding vendored libraries to source control has the disavantage of libraries not being updated...

That all depends on your team's management of your repo.  If everyone ignores the vendor, ya it will get stale.

Personally I make it a "1st of the month" habit of going through and refreshing all dependencies, running our test suites, and if no errors update for QA integration testing on the dev server and keep an eye on the error logs after release.  Tools like `godep` and `gostatus` greatly help keep your GOPATH in chrcn with latest, that you can update your vendor folder(s) with quickly.

Just make sure it is a dedicated commit, so it can be reverted in a hurry if an issue creeps up.

> also heavily polluting the diff of pull requests

First of all, that's just a process task. I enforce rebasing on all pull requests and reject all merges in all repos.  This keeps a very clean git history; but, more to the point, rebasing moves your local commits until after the vendor updates.  Shouldn't ever get a conflict unless someone added the same package.  Which at that point is easy, just take the latest one and be done.

Sound like there are process issues to work out than worrying about /vendor management.